# How to map <Plug>MarkdownPreviewToggle

Tags: map-operator

I am trying to map MarkdownPreviewToggle to an key like "mk". My vimrc is like it:

```
nnoremap mk <Plug>MarkdownPreviewToggle
```

But it doesnt work, what should i do? (the other key isnt work too.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nmap` instead of `nnoremap` for `<Plug>` mappings:

```
nmap mk <Plug>MarkdownPreviewToggle
```

The `<Plug>` mappings are defined by plug-ins, so you need to be able to expand other mappings in your expansion in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! It actually works.

Comment: @BreezyMain you can indicate usefulness with an upvote, and that it solved your problem by accepting the answer.